# How to return a string in the dataGrid.ItemsSource when it contains a ICollection<Continent>

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridviewcolumn, icollection

When im displaying my database table it contains a few collections and those dont display in the datagrid. a column is generated but it stays blank. I do not know where to implement this either.

Maybe this will help also to explain what i want to display in the column instead of the ICollection

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new Whataboutthisfish())
        {
            Vis vis = db.Vissen.Find(2);
            if(vis != null)
            {                    
                if(vis.Continenten != null)
                {
                    string s = "";
                    if(vis.Continenten.Count() > 1)
                    {
                        var continentenLijst = vis.Continenten;

                        s = continentenLijst.First().Naam;
                        foreach (Continent c in vis.Continenten)
                        {
                            s += ", "+c.Naam;
                        }                            
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s = vis.Continenten.First().Naam;
                    }                    
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to return 1 string containing each continent's name using a seperator.

Like: "North-America" if there's only 1 continent in the collection
Or: "North-America, South-America" and so on for multiple.

```
Classes;

[Table("Continenten")]
public partial class Continent
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Continent()
    {
        Vissen = new HashSet<Vis>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Naam { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Vis> Vissen { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
[Table("Vissen")]
public partial class Vis
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Vis()
    {
        Continenten = new HashSet<Continent>();
        Verbanden = new HashSet<Verband>();
        Waterlagen = new HashSet<Waterlaag>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Naam { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Continent> Continenten { get; set; }
}
```

The Xaml for grid:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.833,0.846" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
```

In code behind:

```
using (var db = new Catattafish.Whataboutthisfish())
        {               
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = db.Vissen.ToList(); 
        }
```

Comment: Show us the XAML and the C# code you're having a problem with. You say this is WPF but you show us console code.

Comment: In the question please.

Comment: And show us the Continent class. In the question.

Comment: Updated the original question.

Comment: And db.Vissen is continents? Or fish?